# Moving date of disponibility product

Tags: prestashop

I work on Prestashop 1.7.6.3.
I would like the product availability date to be under the add to cart button instead of being in a tab.
[Screen where i want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwdr1.png)

I try to add this code:

```
    {block name='product_availability_date'}
    {if $product.availability_date}
      <div class="product-availability-date">
        <label>{l s='Availability date:' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'} </label>
        <span>{$product.availability_date}</span>
      </div>
    {/if}
{/block}
```

But it does not update...
can you help me please ?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the selected theme folder->templates/catalog/_partials/product-add-to-cart.tpl.
Find the button HTML and place your code below it.

After the update, make sure you have cleared all cache from admin.

Comment: Thanks Sachin. I add '{$product.availability_date}' after the button and it's ok !!! :)